# MSVC++ Class Cast to the a struct

Tags: visual-c++, casting

I am currently reading an existing code in MS Visual C++ 6.0. I notice a code pattern where they cast object into a structure.

There is a CMemory object.

```
CMemory a;
MY_STRUCTURE_A* a = (MY_STRUCTURE_A*)(void *)a;
MY_STRUCTURE_B* a = (MY_STRUCTURE_B*)(void *)a;
```

I checked the Custom memory class and it really is a class object. It does have a = operator defined but I do not think that would allow it to be reinterpreted to a structure. Why is this being done. How is an object type being cast to different objects?

Any idea why this is being done? I know there is a reinterpret_cast and I am guessing that this technique of casting to void pointer to a structure pointer is similar. But I am not sure if it is the same. Is this pattern safe casting a class object to a struct?

Note: the CMemory is just an arbritary name of the object used. It is not part of the MFC class.

Added based on Necrolis' comment.
The CMemory and it has only 3 members declared in the following order (1) char pointer, (2) int specifying the allocated memory of (1), and (3) a previous and next pointer to other instance of CMemory. It also has a lot of member method. From what I understand, even if I directly cast a class to a structure. The class would start should start with the first member variable which is the char pointer.

```
class CMemory {
public:
    CAMemory();
    ...  Other methods
private:
    char *m_pMemory;
    int m_memorySize;
    ... Other field
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the name of the class and the casting, `CMemory` is more than likely a generic memory block tag (for a GC, arbitrary hash table etc), and to access the memory its tagging requires a cast. Of course this is a "best guess", it means nothing without seeing the full code for `CMemory`.

Is this safe, totally not, its not only UB, but there is no check (at least in your example) as to whether the object you casting to is the object represented by the memory layout. Also, with this being C++, they should be avoiding C casts (as you have noted. the double cast is in fact to get around compiler errors/warnings, which is always the worst way to solve them).

Comment: I added details to the CMemory based on your comment. But I am thinking if the CMemory points to the first member field or to a pointer on a class header maybe 4 bytes of class header. I think it would point to the first member variable which is the memory block.